Finding a manhwa where the male lead is an animal that can turn into a human
The story starts with female lead waking in the novel she was reading.
She has red hair and her father runs a orphanage which contains animals that can turn into human as well as the servants also in their house. In the novel the male lead has white/silver hair and can turn into a animal (can't remember) runs away from home and now lives with the female lead.
With time their bond quite deepens and with season 1 it is found that the father of the male lead has came to the female lead's house to pick up the male lead and take him home.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

I read it on batocomic but now I can't seem to find it. Also the ml initially has long hair but the fl gave it a haircut and also fl took the punishment of hitting with whip of ml by covering him from her father .

I found out the name to be 'I Adopted the Male Lead from the Shelter' or 'I Adopted a Male Lead From a Prison Shelter'

In a universe ripped from the pages of a story, Siena Robert, a self-aware villainess, strives to rewrite her fate. Daughter of a man running a therianthrope shelter, she discovers Ivan Levdilin, the captivating male lead, detained within. Aware of her scripted demise when Ivan's father arrives for his rescue, Siena defies her villainous destiny. She showers Ivan with kindness, a stark contrast to the original Siena's cruel persona. Her actions shield Ivan from her father's cruelty and forge an unscripted bond between them that changes their destiny in an unforeseen direction.
(source: MyAnimeList)

It matches a red-haired female lead and a white/silver-haired male lead who switches to a white leopard.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe the manhwa a bit and explain how it matches the question?

yeah. it also has a red haired female lead and a white/silver male lead who happens to switch to a white leopard. fits the description perfectly!! ><

Please [edit] that information, and any other matching details, into your answer. Please see [answer] for extra tips

Thanks. I couldn't find it as i forgot the name
